# Windows: How to forward all traffic to a Socks Proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, forwarding, socks

i'm using putty to setup a socks proxy on my computer.

i firefox i configure the socks proxy so that i can surf.

but i have to do this for every programm i want to surf the internet.

now, i would like to forward all traffic on windows to my local Socks Proxy. is there something, that could do this job?

see you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set socks proxy on windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1528185/how-can-i-set-socks-proxy-on-windows)

Comment: This is definitely possible on Windows without 3rd party software. I gave a full explanation here: https://superuser.com/a/1618473/396206

Answer (score 1):

I am using Chrome, and an extension called [Switchy!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj) can do the job.

It achieve this by setting some script for the global proxy setting of the system.

I hope this information may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any program to work through socks proxy, you need software like

- FreeCap
- WideCap
- SocksCap
- ProxyCap
- Proxifier
- or even Fiddler.

  It's possible to forward all traffic or from specified applications, some programs allow building of complex rules.

Comment: do they work for all traffic, not only browser(s) traffic... what of this programs do you recommend (from your experience) for Windows... and for Linux...