# How can I set socks proxy on windows?

Tags: proxy

Hi I have a PC with a proxy internet connection. When I use for example flutter it needs to download some dependencies by sock connection. How can I set a global configuration for my PC to use socks connection to internet? Thanks

Comment: Unless the software you are using was built with support for SOCKS proxies, this cannot work. Then, it must also look at the settings you set. Windows software will often (not always!) use the settings from the existing answers. Make sure to check each program's help/documentation.

Answer (score 12):

Windows' basic proxy settings in "Network and Internet" don't seem to actually allow setting a SOCKS proxy explicitly.

To set a SOCKS proxy (SOCKS4 or SOCKS5, I believe) on Windows 10:

1. Take note of your public IP address by [searching Google for "my ip"](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip) (open this in a new tab and keep it open)

[image: External IP address from Google]

1. Open `Internet Options` (either by searching in the start/search bar, or through `Control Panel` > `Network and Internet` > `Internet Options`)

[image: Open internet options]

2. Open the `Connections` tab and click `LAN Settings`

[image: Connections tab]

3. Check the box to "Use a proxy server for your LAN". You'll likely also want to check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses". Then click the "Advanced" button:
   [image: LAN Settings]
4. Uncheck "Use the same proxy server for all protocols", remove all proxy addresses except for "Socks", and replace the Socks address/port with that of your server:

[image: Advanced Proxy Settings]

5. Click OK on the Proxy Settings window, OK on the LAN Settings window, and Apply on the Internet Properties window. All connections should now be going through your SOCKS proxy. Double check by again [searching Google for "my ip"](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip) and comparing to your original external IP address (this should now show the IP address of your SOCKS5 server)

[image: New external IP address reported by Google]

Credit to https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-socks5-proxy-settings/ for getting me pointed in the right direction, after trying the suggestions on this page

Answer (score 7):

To set the SOCKS proxy on Windows 11, set the protocol and the equal signal before the address of proxy:

[image: how to set the socks proxy on windows11]

I use it with ssh/putty to make a vpn.

Comment: Done! I forgot to specify that it is to Windows 11 version.

Comment: But what about password? Where to enter it?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 10 proxy setup UI is terrible.

To use socks, you need to enter this into the address field:

`http://socks=localhost`

Replace localhost with the actual proxy address.

Set the port as per usual.

Comment: Hrm, this doesn't seem to be working... afaict this is just causing windows to ignore the proxy setting completely (unlike just putting in `localhost`, which causes the connection to fail completely)

Comment: The only answer which made it for me. Now just wondering where is this documented.

Comment: I found this by accessing the old system Proxy Configuration (eg, via Internet Explorer), setting the SOCKS proxy through that, and then observing what happened to the Windows 10 proxy setting.

Likely, this isn't actually documented anywhere.

Comment: Actually, you have to type here just `socks=localhost`. Then if the windows is closed and reopened, it will prepend `http://` to it making it an invalid configuration. If then you accept that it will just silently ignore it, so it looks like it is accepting it, but it is doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows 10, follow the steps below to set proxy:

> 1. Open Settings.
> 2. Click Network & Internet.
> 3. Click Proxy.
> 4. In the Manual Proxy Setup section, set the Use a Proxy Server switch to On.
> 5. In the Address field, type the IP address.
> 6. In the Port field, type the port.
> 7. Click Save; then close the Settings window.

[image]

There is 4 main types of proxy:

- HTTP — allows to visit web-sites and download files from HTTP.
- HTTPS — also called SSL proxies. With these proxies you can view HTTP and HTTPS sites.With special software they may be used with any protocol like SOCKS proxies.
- Socks 4 — can be used with any TCP/IP protocol with any destination address and port..
- Socks 5 — you may also use UDP protocol, make DNS requests, und use BIND function for port forwarding.

Comment: I did that. But I have a socks error when I use flutter.

Comment: Then your sock/proxy doesn't work, or couldn't connect. Which one you use? A proxy server from a website, or SSH?

Comment: Well, I am not sure about this. I guess that it is a proxy server from a website.  I just know that my proxy is a IP:port. Sock is a proxy feature?? Is possible that my proxy works ok with http protocol and not works with sock protocol?? Thank.

Comment: It's possible. You can go to https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/ and get a few other proxies to test whether it's work or not.

Comment: Ok I understand. Is there any way to redirect the socks request to http?

Comment: I don't understand your purpose. If you want to use SOCK4 or 5 proxy, just set up it on your computer and use your web browser to load http or https websites normally. All connections will go through this proxy.

Comment: My web browser works fine with my proxy configuration. The problem is when I use the terminal to run flutter i got a socket  error. Then I guess my sock proxy is not work or not configured or any other option.

Comment: I haven't used Flutter before so I couldn't give you the best solution at all. But there was a software I often use to cover the entire computer with proxy, which is better Windows' function. It's Proxifier (https://www.proxifier.com/). There is a trial that you can try.

Comment: This doesn't seem to let you set a SOCKS proxy. See [my answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1618473/396206) about setting a SOCKS proxy explicitly

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to set a socks proxy in windows 10 was via Internet Explorer.
Search for and run the Internet Explorer App.
From the Tools menu click on Internet Options.
Click on the Connections tab.
Click the "LAN settings" button.
Add a check to the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" if its not already checked.
Click on the Advanced setting
Uncheck the box for "Use the same proxy server for all protocols" if it's checked.
Set your SOCKS server here and clear the fields for all the other proxy types.
Click OK, click OK, click OK, and now your system is configured to use a SOCKS proxy.